# Why is it not allowed to create a view for `std::owning_view`?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

According to [cppreference std::ranges::viewable_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/viewable_range),

```cpp
template<class T>
concept viewable_range =
  ranges::range<T> &&
  ((ranges::view<std::remove_cvref_t<T>> &&
    std::constructible_from<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, T>) ||
   (!ranges::view<std::remove_cvref_t<T>> &&
    (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T> ||
     (std::movable<std::remove_reference_t<T>> && !/*is-initializer-list*/<T>))));
```

For a view to be `viewable_range` and thus be able to be passed to range adaptors, it must be an **rvalue** or **copyable lvalue**.

Why do we need to make this constraint that **lvalue view has to be copyable**? For example, why is it not allowed to create a view for `std::owning_view`? My guess is that it's because `some_wrapper_view<std::ranges::owning_view>` must be an owning view and it needs to move from `std::ranges::owning_view`, is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, why is it not allowed to create a view for
> `std::owning_view`?

Theoretically, it is feasible. For the lvalue non-copyable `view`, we can still wrap it through `ref_view`, but this will get a reference to the `view`, which is contrary to the design intention of the `view` because the `view` is usually passing by value.

Paper [P2636](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2636r2.html) worries that the current design may introduce some inconsistencies because range adaptors can always work with lvalue ranges but cannot work with specific lvalue `view`s, where `view` just range with additional properties.

However, this proposal was [rejected](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1302) by the committee because this change to allow references to `view` does not lead to many compelling use cases.